# Incorrect output for infix to binary tree converter

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, output, binary-tree

I have written a code taking an expression in infix notation and I am turning the expression into a binary tree.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I have the program compiling but the output is incorrect, it should print out the original statement, then the inorder statement without parentheses, then preorder statement & postorder statement.  What do I need to fix to get the correct output?

My current output:

```
( ( 6 + 2 ) - 5 ) * 8 / 2
* 
* 
*
```

The Correct output:

```
(( 6 + 2 ) - 5 ) * 8 / 2
6 + 2 - 5 * 8 / 2
/ * - + 6 2 5 8 2
6 2 + 5 - 8 * 2 /
```

My Main method:

```
public class Prog5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    InFixToBinaryTreeConverter fp = new InFixToBinaryTreeConverter();
    fp.run("( ( 6 + 2 ) - 5 ) * 8 / 2");
}
}
```

My Node Class:

```
public class Node<String> {
    protected String element;
    protected Node<String> left;
    protected Node<String> right;
    int x; 

    public Node(String e, Node left, Node right){
        element = e; //data = element
        this.left = this.right = null;
    }
}
```

My InFixToBinaryTreeConverter class:

```
public class InFixToBinaryTreeConverter{

List<String> stack = new ArrayList<>(); //stack
List<String> inFix= new LinkedList<>(); //queue
List<Node> btstack = new ArrayList<>(); //stack
private String expression;
Node root = null;

//create a no-arg consutrctor that initializes the inFix, stack , & btstack lists
InFixToBinaryTreeConverter(){
    this.inFix = inFix;
    this.stack = stack;
    this.btstack = btstack;
}



public void run(String s){ // run method is driver for program
    this.expression = s;
    System.out.println(expression);
    createInFix();
    createBinaryTree();
    printInorder(btstack.get(0));
    System.out.println();
    printPreorder(btstack.get(0));
    System.out.println();
    printPostorder(btstack.get(0));
}

public void createInFix(){
    String[] temporary = expression.split("\\s+"); 

    for (int i = 0; i < temporary.length; i++ ){
        inFix.add(temporary[i]);
    }
}

public void createBinaryTree(){
    stack.add("(");
    inFix.add(")");

    while(!inFix.isEmpty()){
        String variable = inFix.remove(0);
        if(isANumber(variable)){
            Node nodeNew = new Node(variable, null, null);
            btstack.add(nodeNew);
        }
        else if(isLeftParentheses(variable)){
            stack.add(variable);
        }
        if(isOperator(variable)){
            while(precedence(stack.get(stack.size() - 1), variable)){
                Node rightChild = btstack.remove(btstack.size() - 1);
                Node leftChild = btstack.remove(btstack.size() - 1);
                Node nodeNew = new Node(variable, rightChild, leftChild);
                btstack.add(nodeNew);
            }

            stack.add(variable);
        }
        if(isRightParentheses(variable)){
            if(stack.get(stack.size() -1 ) != null){
                while(!isLeftParentheses(stack.get(stack.size() - 1))){
                    String temporary = stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
                    Node rightChild2 = btstack.remove(btstack.size() - 1);
                    Node leftChild2 = btstack.remove(btstack.size() - 1);
                    btstack.add(new Node(temporary, leftChild2, rightChild2));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public static boolean isANumber(String str){
        boolean isANumber = false;
        if(str.charAt(0) >= '0' && str.charAt(0) <= '9'){
            isANumber = true;
        }
        return isANumber;
    }

    public static boolean isOperator(String str){ //check to see if c is an operator
        boolean isOperator = false;
        if("+".equals(str) || "-".equals(str) || "*".equals(str) || "/".equals(str)){
            return true;
        }
        return isOperator;
    }

    public boolean precedence(String operator1, String operator2){
        boolean precedence = false;
        int compareTo = operator1.compareTo(operator2);
        if(compareTo >= 0){
            precedence = true;
        }
        return precedence;
    }

    public boolean isLeftParentheses(String x) {
        boolean isLeftParentheses = false;
        if(x.equals("(")){
            isLeftParentheses = true;
        }
        return isLeftParentheses;
    }
    public boolean isRightParentheses(String x) {
        boolean isRightParentheses = false;
        if(x.equals(")")){
            isRightParentheses = true;
        }
        return isRightParentheses;
    }

    public void process(Node node){
       System.out.print(node.elementr+ " ");
   }
    /* Given a binary tree, print its nodes in inorder*/
    public void printInorder(Node node){
        if (node != null){
            printInorder(node.left); // first recur on left child 
            process(node); // then print the data of node 
            printInorder(node.right); // now recur on right child 
        }
    }

    /* Given a binary tree, print its nodes in preorder*/
    public void printPreorder(Node node){
        if (node != null){
            process(node); // first print data of node 
            printPreorder(node.left); // then recur on left sutree 
            printPreorder(node.right); // now recur on right subtree 
        }
    }
    public void printPostorder(Node node){
        if (node != null){
            printPreorder(node.left); // then recur on left sutree 
            printPreorder(node.right); // now recur on right subtree
            process(node); // first print data of node 

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just starting your prints at the wrong end. The top of the stack is the last element in list, not the first.

It would have made your life easier if you had used a `Stack`, and `push()` and `pop()`, and started the ordered printouts at `stack.peek()`.